# Автосгенерированная ложь или из текста удален 1 символ

Tags: дефект, предложение, локализация

Наверное, каждый, кто хотя бы раз делал правку сообщения и оставлял при этом поле "Описание" пустым, наблюдал в истории ревизий текст вида:

> из текста удален 1 символ

> в текст добавлено 42 символа

> изменённое тело сообщения

[Последний вариант](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33269670#33269670) уже исправлен и скоро должен быть доступен на сайте. Но вопрос сейчас о первых двух вариантах, которые, хотя и являются подходящим переводом исходных фраз:

> deleted $numChars$ characters in body

> added $numChars$ characters in body

но, тем не менее, [не отражают действительности](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/105/revisions):

[image: форум-сайт]

В приведенном примере слово "форум" заменено на "сайт". И такое изменение можно лишь с натяжкой обозвать "из текста удален 1 символ".

Предлагаю в подобных ситуациях не полагаться на прямой перевод текста, а всё-таки отражать реальную ситуацию. Предлагайте ваши варианты в ответах или голосуйте за имеющиеся.

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант мне кажется более соответствующим реальной ситуации:

> размер тела сообщения уменьшился на 1 символ

> размер тела сообщения увеличился на 42 символа

Comment: а чем лучше громоздкое  "размер тела сообщения" вместо обычного "текст"?

Comment: @Утка тем, что согласуется в третьим вариантом, когда объем текста не изменился. Но его тоже можно будет подправить. Оформите лучше Вашу версию отдельным ответом. Устроим демократические выборы :)

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативный (утиный) вариант:

> текст уменьшился на 1 символ

> текст увеличился на 42 символа

Однако такой вариант подразумевает, что под термином "текст" скрывается именно информационный объём, а не смысловой. Это будет проблематично согласовать с третьей формой, когда кол-во символов не изменилось, но текст при этом поменялся.

Answer (score 0):

Многим из нас привычен формат diff:

```
 foo.txt  | 26 ++++++++++++++++++++++----
 bar.txt  | 24 ++++++++++++++++++++----
 fizz.txt | 13 +++++++++++--
 3 files changed, 53 insertions(+), 10 deletions(-)
```

Хотелось бы сохранять оба числа, т.к. их сумма не имеет смысла. Да, для этого понадобится переделывать движок сайта, но решения в рамках текущего поведения выглядят костылями. Можно убрать 1000 символов и добавить 1001, а сообщение будет "добавлен 1 символ".

> в текст добавлено N символов, удалено M символов
> в текст добавлено N символов
> из текста удалено M символов

Для реализации понадобятся следующие шаблонные строки, c учётом локализации

> $added$ and $removed$ characters in body
> в текст $added$ и $removed$ символов
>
> $added$ in body
> в текст $added$
>
> $removed$ characters in body
> из текста $removed$

added (one|few|many):

> added $numAdded$ character
> добавлен $numAdded$ символ
>
> added $numAdded$ characters
> добавлено $numAdded$ символа
>
> added $numAdded$ characters
> добавлено $numAdded$ символов

removed (one|few|many) - аналогично.

В результате можно будет получить строки с двумя степенями свободы по (one|few|many):

> в текст добавлено 20 символов и удалён 1 символ
>
> в текст добавлен 21 символ и удалено 5 символов
>
> в текст добавлено 23 символа
>
> из текста удалено 8 символов

При реализации нужно убедиться, что на всех языках подстановка двух частей в третью строку возможна. Если нет, то придётся делать девять строк, по матрице `(one|few|many) Х (one|few|many)`

Comment: Всё это хорошо, но хотелось бы видеть вариант, достижимый путем редактирования transifex, а не изменением движка. Если есть более менее приемлемый способ сделать это не прибегая к услугам разработчиков, лучше его использовать побыстрее, а не ждать пока (и если) в движок добавят ещё одну переменную.